# What is the correct way to create a Graph In ArangoDB

Tags: graph, document, traversal, arangodb

I'm using ArangoDB 3.1.25

I have two files; one is in the form of **documents** and the other is imported as an **edge collection** 
In order to do a graph operation such as traversal via the shortest path, I found that I need to create a graph.

Here is my **documents schema**

```
{"reference":"9606.ENSP00000377461;","Entry":"Q3LIC1"}
```

and **edge schema**

```
{"Id":"8075502","_from":"p1/9606.ENSP00000361446","_to":"p2/9606.ENSP00000223073","s":315}
```

doing this, I get an empty graph as a result. What am I missing?

Comment: I wish their documentation was as good as mongodb